# CodeSmith.Data Reference not found

Tags: codesmith

I am using CodeSmith tool to generate code. but by mistake i removed the Reference CodeSmith.Data and now i can't found it, or where must be to add it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you regenerate the code using the CodeSmith Generator Project file (.csp) then the reference will be readded. Otherwise the reference can be found inside of the Templates Common\v4.0 folder.